# React load only new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a grid layout which displays 9 images. I fetch the images from an API:

```
  getImages() {
    let url =
      'URL';
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ posts: data.posts, isLoading: false }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages();

  }
```

At the bottom is a button to load more images. If I click on the button the getImages() function loads 9 more images. But I have 2 problems.
The first problem is that the columns "jump" for a few seconds from three columns too two columns and back. The second problem is that I only want to load new images. That means that the 9 inital images should be visible all the time and if I click on the button than under the images should appear a loading spinner until the next images are loaded and ready to display.

Comment: Try: `posts: (this.state.posts || []).concat(data.posts)`. This will keep the old posts, your current approach replaces them.

Comment: but then I have duplicates of images

Comment: I thought `getImages` will load 9 new images. If that is the case, you shouldn't have duplicates. `this.state.posts` will be the old images and `data.posts` the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Merge your arrays, but filter duplicates first. Since I don't know your exact data structure for `posts`, I will assume there is a unique `id` property in the sample below:

```
.then(data => {
    const { posts } = this.state;

    // Extract post ids that have already been stored in state.
    // Then, filter your response posts based on their id not existing in the postIds array.
    const postIds = posts.map(p => p.id);
    const newPosts = data.posts.filter(p => postIds.indexOf(p.id) === -1);
    const mergedPosts = [ ...posts, ...newPosts ];

    this.setState({ posts: mergedPosts });
});
```

I'm not sure what could be causing the columns jumping - I think I'd need more info on your overall layout/css.

Comment: I have created a masonry grid layout with flexbox. I have a function to calculate the number of columns. This function gets called when I load new post items. If I have for example a container with a width of 1200px. Then I have a function to calculate how many columns my masonry grid has. For example: 3 posts with 300px width. When I click on the "load more items" button then the function to calculate my columns gets called and then I call the function getPosts() to load the new images

Comment: I'd need to see a bit of your code for the whole component that is managing the calling of those calculations and how they are used in the `render`. I can only throw out some theories that it could be related to stale state values being rendered temporarily, you might need to add keys, or something related to any intercepting lifecyle functions you might have that change the state on update.